# xsl - multiple xsl:if with the same condition

Tags: xslt, if-statement

Newbie question on xslt. I've multiple xsl:if checks like

```
<xsl:if test="node/node1"> ...</xsl:if>
...
<xsl:if test="node/node1"> ...</xsl:if>
...
<xsl:if test="node/node1"> ... </xsl:if>
```

Is there a way to parameterize the test condition to make the code more readable and easy to maintain? Maybe with a variable or something like

```
<xsl:variable name="node1Present" select="true()"/>
<xsl:if test="$node1Present"> ... </xsl:if>
```

I don't understand how to construct the variable to reflect the 'test a node exist' (test="node/node1")

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a recommendation of a better refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="node1Present" select="boolean(node/node1)"/>
```

For node-sets, `boolean()` converts to true, if and only if the node-set is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

In XPath, any expression that does return a truthy (i.e. non-empty) value is considered as `true` in boolean context.

```
<xsl:variable name="node1Present" select="node/node1"/>
<xsl:if test="$node1Present"> ... </xsl:if>
```

It's not that *trying it* would have made the world explode. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the correct answers so far, I would recommend the following refactoring:

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:if test="node/node1"> ...</xsl:if> 
... 
<xsl:if test="node/node1"> ...</xsl:if> 
... 
<xsl:if test="node/node1"> ... </xsl:if>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:if test="node/node1"> ...</xsl:if> 
...
```

or with:

```
... 
<xsl:if test="node/node1"> ... </xsl:if>
```

That is, put all code that depends on the condition in a single `<xsl:if>`.

It would be very interesting if you could present code that cannot be refactored in this way. :)

Comment: well '...' means that between every xsl:if there's other code ... !

Comment: @mickthomposn: I know that. What I am saying that this code need not be dispersed at all! You *can* group all dependent code under a single `<xsl:if>`. If you show your code, many people will be able to help you with this, *better*, refactoring.